# Ruby yard doc not showing any files

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc, yard

This is my setup:

- Ruby 1.9.2 p290
- Yard 0.8.1

The folder structure is not a gem, just plain old Ruby code:

```
.
├── classes
│   ├── crawl.rb
│   └── page.rb
└── run.rb
```

The problem is that yard does not see any files.

`yard doc` yields this output:

```
 Files:           0
 Modules:         0 (    0 undocumented)
 Classes:         0 (    0 undocumented)
 Constants:       0 (    0 undocumented)
 Methods:         0 (    0 undocumented)
 0.00% documented
```

Any ideas why it can't see any of my files, or isn't

---

Edit (Additional info):

Yard does have permissions to create files.

After I run the `yard doc` command, my directory shows yard files:

```
.       ..      .yardoc classes doc     run.rb
```

---

Edit (response to comment about rdoc)

Once I delete the doc folder that yard creates (rdoc complains about it) `rm -rf doc`, rdoc generates documentation and provides this output

```
 Files:       7

 Classes:     6 ( 4 undocumented)
 Modules:     0 ( 0 undocumented)
 Constants:   2 ( 2 undocumented)
 Attributes: 18 (18 undocumented)
 Methods:    24 (20 undocumented)

 Total:      50 (44 undocumented)
  12.00% documented
```

---

Edit (Additional info)

Yard does not work for me on other ruby builds including MRI 1.8.7 and jRuby 1.6.4. It behaves the same way as described above

Comment: What is your working directory when you issue that command?

Comment: Working directory is the same as where my files are. It is the same as when I issued the tree command for the example folder structure above.

Comment: What happens when you try to use rdoc instead of yard? That'd help triangulate whether it's a yard problem exclusively, or a system/configuration issue.

Comment: rdoc works, I edited the post above so that I could post the output in a long block. see "Edit (response to comment about rdoc)" above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yard does not automatically document all ruby files in a directory structure. It looks for files in a `./lib` directory. If you want to document others, you must specify that in the command or in a .yardopts file

example
`yard classes/*.rb *.rb`